# What is the use of const std::vector?

Tags: c++

I've seen code that uses a `const std::vector`, however can't see why it wouldn't make more sense to simply use an `std::array` instead.

The values for the vector seem to be initialized at compile-time.

What is the benefit of a `const std::vector`?

Edit: The vector was not big, only a couple of strings, however I see that this may be one advantage.

Comment: Perhaps the vector is large in size making an array be too large for a stack / automatic storage.

Comment: This usually happens because someone reaches for the most familiar type when they first write the code, then never goes back and refactors to the more optimal type. It's unlikely to make a big difference, anyway.

Comment: This code may have been written for C++98/03.

Comment: I'm not sure it's easily answerable without us seeing what you have. It's a pretty broad question without a bit more context. *and the amount of divergence in answers and comments is further evidence of that*

Comment: `const` doesn't mean that the size is known at the compile-time. For example: `const std::vector<T> data = makeData();`. Functional style typically results in more clear code.

Comment: Since the values in vector are initialized at compile time, which requires c++20,  just return a const reference to it. You could also change to `std::array` but there's little advantage. Most of the memory will be in the strings, not the small amount of extra overhead of a vector instance.

Answer (score 5):

`const std::vector` lets you have a "fixed sized array" whose size you only know at run time but still allows you to have all the benefits of a standard container. If you used a raw/smart pointer in your code you will need to manually pass the size of the array that it points to into the function(s) that need to know the size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::vector` could be used with a large list of data, because it could use Dynamic Allocated Array to store values and before C++20 it's doesn't have a `constexpr` constructor. But `std::array` uses a raw C-Array and it could be used at compile time with the stack size restricted list of data. So:

`std::array const` is good for:

- Where your data size is less than the stack size.
- [Where data locality is important](https://akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).
- You want your list at the compile time (before C++20).

`std::vector const` is good for:

- Where your data size is large than the stack size.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common to see C++ code that expects references to vectors, sometimes const, something like this:

```
auto do_sum(std::vector<int> const& numbers) -> int {
    return std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);
}
```

Even though the good intentions are not about not copying memory, this code require the caller to allocate a `std::vector`, even though the amount of value and the actual values might be known at compile time.

This might be fixed by using a span instead:

```
auto do_sum(std::span<int const> numbers) -> int {
    return std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);
}
```

Now this code don't require the users to allocate a vector for the array, and might use `std::array`, or plain C arrays.

---

Also, sometimes you don't know what are the numbers of element the array can have, and might be determined at runtime. Consider this:

```
auto create_vector() -> std::vector<int> {
    auto vec = std::vector<int>{};

    if (/* runtime condition */) {
        vec.push_back(1);
        vec.push_back(2);
        vec.push_back(3);
    } else {
        vec.push_back(4);
        vec.push_back(5);
    }
    
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> const vec = create_vector();
}
```

As you can see here, as the vector is moved from scope to scope, the const-ness changes and is expressing the intent of the developer to only make it mutable in some initializing scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `std::array` needs you to specify the size as part of the type. By using `std::vector` the compiler can work that out for your dynamically.

This matters in maintenance situations as it prevents errors. You only add/remove a string from the initializer of the object and the vector will have the correct size automatically. If you use an array you need to add/remove the string and change the type of the array.

```
 const std::vector<std::string>     dataV = { "A", "B", "C" };
 const std::array<std::string, 3>   dataA = { "A", "B", "C" };
```

If I now modify these to only have two values.

```
 // The vector will auto resize
 const std::vector<std::string>     dataV = { "A", "B"};

 // This will still be of size three.
 // This is not usually what you want.
 const std::array<std::string, 3>   dataA = { "A", "B"};

 // The person modifying the code has to manually spot that and
 // change the type to explicitly have two member array. Note
 // It may not be as obvious as you think as the type may 
 // be hidden with a type alias of some description

 using DataStore = std::array<std::string, 3>;

 /// Lots of code:
 DataStore dataA = { "A", "B"};   // Would you have spotted.
```